# Attemping to upload multiple photos instead of 1 - Laravel

Tags: image, laravel, laravel-5, src

I have a property ad, which has a field to upload photos. It 'seems' to upload them with no errors, but I can't display them. I get the missing image icon. Here is my code

FORM

```
          <form method="POST" action="/property" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="photo" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Images</label>
                      <div class="col-md-9">
                        <input required type="file" class="form-control" name="photo[]" placeholder="address" multiple>
                      </div>
                    </div>

         </form>
```

Store Controller

```
public function store(Request $request){

      $input=$request->all();
      $images=array();
      if($files=$request->file('photo')){
        foreach($files as $file){
          $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
          $file->move('photo', $name);
          $images[]=$name;
        }
      }
    $Advert = PropertyAdvert::create([
        //"photo"       => base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->photo->path())),
        'photo'=>  implode("|",$images),
        "address"     => $request->address,
        "county"      => $request->county,
        "town"        => $request->town,
        "type"        => $request->type,
        "rent"        => $request->rent,
        "date"        => $request->date,
        "bedrooms"    => $request->bedrooms,
        "bathrooms"   => $request->bathrooms,
        "furnished"   => $request->furnished,
        "description" => $request->description,
        "user_id" => Auth::id(),
    ]);

    $id = $Advert->id;

    return redirect("/property/$id");
  }
```

Any ideas?

EDIT

This is the migration file. As you can see the photo field is the first one.

```
Schema::create('property_adverts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->binary('photo');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->string('county');
            $table->string('town');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->string('rent');
            $table->string('date');
            $table->string('bedrooms');
            $table->string('bathrooms');
            $table->string('furnished');
            $table->longText('description');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
```

Show Page Code

```
<div class="card-body col-md-12">
      @foreach ($Advert as $Ad)
        <img src="data:image/gif;base64,{{ $Ad['photo'] }}" class="img-fluid full-width col-md-12">
      @endforeach

    </div>
```

Comment: Is your picture store in your database ?

Comment: Yes. It's one of the columns in the PropertyAdvert table. I have added the migration code to the quesiton.

Comment: If the value is stored, in your database, and the image in your server, the "update" function is not the function sense to be showing the picture. In which function do you want to show the picture ? which blade view ?

Comment: the data is stored but you are not able to retrieve it is it ?

Comment: yes show the code which is used to show the image

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to post the show page.

Comment: It's posted now.

Comment: Anyone have any idea?